# Как сделать Bottom Navigation чтобы у каждой вкладки был свой стэк активити

Tags: android, android-studio, bottom-navigation-view

Хочу реализовать подобный Bottom Navigation как в Vk, Facebook, Inst.
Чтобы у каждой вкладки был свой стэк активити. Я не знаю как по-нормальному это объяснить.
Для более точного понимания моей идеи вот схема внизу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что подразумевается под "стэком" в данном случае? Поясните получше, желательно на примере.

Comment: стэк активити. backStack. вот как на картинке.

Comment: назначить на каждую кнопку по активити, из которых будут вызываться следующие активити/фрагменты? Поясните, в чем видите трудность.

Comment: но а стэк то будет один. вы пользовались вк, фб ил инстой?

Comment: а BottomNavigation тут при чем? Тут логика определятся не в нем, а в самих активити/фрагментах. К сожалению, не пользовался ничем из перечисленного, но, я так понимаю, после переключения на другую вкладку, на предыдущей остается контент, который был открыт?

Comment: дадада. именно так. извините за задержку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все, что вы нарисовали на схеме, выражается в коде примерно так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;
public static final String TAB_HOME  = "tab_home";
public static final String TAB_DASHBOARD  = "tab_dashboard";
public static final String TAB_NOTIFICATIONS  = "tab_notifications";

private String mCurrentTab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
    mStacks.put(TAB_HOME, new Stack<Fragment>());
    mStacks.put(TAB_DASHBOARD, new Stack<Fragment>());
    mStacks.put(TAB_NOTIFICATIONS, new Stack<Fragment>());

    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                selectedTab(TAB_HOME);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                selectedTab(TAB_DASHBOARD);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                selectedTab(TAB_NOTIFICATIONS);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

private void gotoFragment(Fragment selectedFragment)
{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, selectedFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private void selectedTab(String tabId)
{
    mCurrentTab = tabId;

    if(mStacks.get(tabId).size() == 0){
        if(tabId.equals(TAB_HOME)){
            pushFragments(tabId, new HomeFragment(),true);
        }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_DASHBOARD)){
            pushFragments(tabId, new DashboardFragment(),true);
        }else if(tabId.equals(TAB_NOTIFICATIONS)){
            pushFragments(tabId, new NotificationsFragment(),true);
        }
    }else {
        pushFragments(tabId, mStacks.get(tabId).lastElement(),false);
    }
}

public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment, boolean shouldAdd){
    if(shouldAdd)
        mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

public void popFragments(){
    Fragment fragment = mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).elementAt(mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() - 2);

    mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).pop();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() == 1){
        finish();
        return;
    }

    popFragments();
    }
 }
```

Пример добавления нового фрагмента в стек вкладки HOME:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Button gotoNextFragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gotoHome2);

    gotoNextFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).pushFragments(MainActivity.TAB_HOME, new Home2Fragment(),true);
        }
    });
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>(); а на месте Fragment писать класс фрагмента?

Comment: @PavelVorobyov базового класса ваших фрагментов, они же наследуются от Fragment, поэтому и оставляйте Fragment.

Comment: т.е. "Fragment" ничем не заменяется

Comment: почему "fragment" подчеркивается красным? ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment); класс Fragment импортировал

Comment: @PavelVorobyov а что вам студия подсказывает?

Comment: в том то и дело что ничего

Comment: @PavelVorobyov а при компиляции ошибки есть?